# iOS Designer on a Xamarin Forms app keeps saying a Max is needed but am connected already successfully

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I saw this was an error previous in the 15.x version of VS 2019; but wondering if it is back again.

Currently running Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.3. I had no issues at all doing the Android side of the house nor even the regular iOS parts of the app.

But now I need to configure the splash/loading screen specifically for iOS and am having trouble getting the iOS Designer to load on my PC within VS 2019 when trying to load the .storyboard files with a borrowed Mac on my home network.

I've loaded Xcode and Xcode Tools on the Mac, made a new Admin account that is tied to my AppleID that is on the Team of an active Apple Dev account.

I've also launched Xcode and accepted all the licensing stuff, have even started a new Storyboard app, built and and launched it into the Simulator on the Mac (Macbook Pro 1). I have tried disabling/re-enabling Hot Restart (along with restarting Visual Studio.)

I'm admittedly new to the iOS half of the house but I can't see what's wrong here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, do you refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos#related-links) to edit splash screen in iOS solution?

Comment: Hey! I did. The trick really is just after clicking to edit a storyboard with the iOS Designer, and it shows you need an active connection to Mac click the Pair to Mac button/UI and click the Add Mac button. Just re-type in the same IP of the Mac you've already added and it will connect. You basically just re-add it each time. It does add a +1 Mac to the list (one with the name and one with the IP) but it does work.

Unfortunately, even after setting the storyboard as the LaunchScreen within the Info.plist file, it still fails to show on my test iPhone 6S; even after being able to design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug again as of Dec 2020:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1185638/xamarin-ios-designer-now-working-in-vs-2019-previe.html

Comment: Hi, if be sure it's an issue, remember to mark this as the answer. Then others who have the same problem will know that.